# Best way to limit the number of records in table in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `users` table. The number of users should be limited to 100. That is, once the number of users reaches 100, I cannot add any user anymore.

The first thing I have in mind is to query first for the number of rows returned by the `select * from users`. If the number of rows returned is < 100, I can still add more users. Else, I can't anymore.

That would take 2 queries to meet my needs. Any idea how to have it in only 1 query? I have come across into using the `trigger` statement but I would like to know if it is a good idea. Please add code snippet as an example.

Comment: Which SQL server are you using?

Comment: the best way is to do it in application i mean in front end

Comment: Agreed it is probably best to do it in the front end as @skhurams suggests, then have a trigger only as a backup plan (in case two different people add users #100 and #101 at the same time, the second will throw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say, **best way to handle this through front end..**

Here is **another option**..

If you have an Identity column in the table , you could add  a constraint for this table..

```
ALTER TABLE <your_table>
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_users
CHECK( <identity_column> < 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a normal way to use an RDBMS, so that's why there's not a simple way to do it.

<strike>Probably the way I would do this is to write a stored procedure and call it instead of the insert.  The stored procedure would essentially encapsulate your two-query solution but at the database layer.</strike>  (EDIT - no sprocs in sqlite)

However it's important to consider **why** you need to limit the number of users.  If it's a situation where you can only have 100 active users at a time, then I would strongly consider instead storing all of the users, but also storing a state indicating whether they are active or not.  That gives you the opportunity to move inactive users to active and vice versa... that's just one scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's always a good idea to have the database make sure the data is clean if it can do so.

A double layer approach where you have the trigger to make sure data is good and check in the application too might be good.